# Classify scraped results side by side into a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, scrapy

So I'm using python/scrapy to scrape data from a webpage. Basically the webpage is made of 15 blocks that contain various sort of information. My spider reiterates through every block to scrape some specific content. I'm happy with the content of the results, but not with how the data is presented. I want all the scraped information belonging in one block to be presented in a single row. You will see from the screenshot below that the results of the same block are not presented side by side, which is what I want.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for i in response.css('span.dir'):
        yield {'address': i.css('b::text').extract()}
    for l in response.css('div.datos'):
        yield {'area': l.css('i::text').extract()}
    for x in response.css('div.opciones'):
        yield {'price stable': x.css('span.eur::text').extract()}
    for o in response.css('div.opciones'):
        yield {'price drop': o.css('div.mp_pvpant.baja::text').extract()}
    for y in response.css('div.opciones'):
        yield {'price decreased': y.css('span.eur_m::text').extract()}
    for u in response.css('div.datos'):
        yield {'link': u.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()}
```

[image: Results of scrapy]

Comment: where is the part of code where you save in the file ?

Comment: actually after that in the script there is no code for saving the file. I open the command prompt in the scrapy.cfg file and run the spider and save the file as well as .json. --> scrapy crawl xxx -o yyy.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is the same number of results on each row you can do this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    addresses = []
    areas = []
    prices_stable = []
    prices_drop = []
    prices_decreased = []
    links = []
    for i in response.css('span.dir'):
        addresses.append(i.css('b::text').extract())
    for l in response.css('div.datos'):
        areas.append(l.css('i::text').extract())
    for x in response.css('div.opciones'):
        prices_stable.append(x.css('span.eur::text').extract())
    for o in response.css('div.opciones'):
        prices_drop.append(o.css('div.mp_pvpant.baja::text').extract())
    for y in response.css('div.opciones'):
        prices_decreased.append(y.css('span.eur_m::text').extract())
    for u in response.css('div.datos'):
        links.append(u.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first())

    for address, area, price_stable, price_drop, price_decreased, link in zip(addresses, areas, prices_stable, prices_drop, prices_decreased, links):
        yield {
            'address': address,
            'area': area,
            'price_stable': price_stable,
            'price_drop': price_drop,
            'price_decreased': price_decreased,
            'link': link,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append extracted values into a list and then yield the same, like this

```
def parse(self, response):
    # create more lists for the remaining fields
    address = []
    area = []
    for i in response.css('span.dir'):
        address.append(i.css('b::text').extract())
    yield {'address':address}
    for l in response.css('div.datos'):
        area.append(l.css('i::text').extract())
    yield {'area':area}
```